# Force Outlook 2003 to run a server side rule on the client

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2003, rules

I have the following rule in Outlook which moves all emails involving meetings into a different folder within the Inbox.

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
uses the 'Tentative Meeting Response' or 'Decline Meeting Response' or 'Accept Meeting Response' or 'Meeting Cancellation' or 'Meeting Request' form
move it to the Meetings folder
```

The problem is that Outlook forces this rule to be run server side, which that meetings aren't shown in the inbox of my Blackberry when Outlook is off.

The ideal solution would be to only run this rule when Outlook is running (as in, make it client side). This would mean that when my PC is off, I'd see the invites in the inbox of the Blackberry but as soon as my PC is turned on, Outlook would load and run and they would get moved out of the inbox.

However I'm unable to work out how to force this rule to run on the client. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Outlook to hand but does adding "On this machine only" to the rule not have the desired effect?

Comment: +1 This is correct; it's the bottom entry of "Select Conditions" step when creating or editing a rule.

Comment: I'm an idiot, completely missed that. Thanks.